# ARP Requests causing network disconnection

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, arp

Firstly, apologies if this is the wrong forum, happy to be pointed in the right direction...

Recently got new Internet from Virgin Media and have been having constant network issues with them since on my PC.

I used Wireshark to trace any potential issues and identified that at the point of disconnect, an ARP request is sent to the routers IP. Therefore, intermitentally dropping connection.

I have tried a new PCI-E wifi adapter, and tried direct Ethernet into my motherboard and have seen this persist. I have also done a frehs install of Windows.

With a technician coming out on friday, I wanted to know if there's any way of solving this myself prior to.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the connection is lost after the ARP request and not before? It could just as well be that the ARP is _caused by_ the OS checking whether the gateway is not dead after not receiving any packets from it (which, AFAIK, Windows does for IPv4 as well). Does the router have an IPv6 address of any sort; does that remain reachable? Do any other devices in your LAN remain reachable?

Comment: The events are pretty much simultaneous. As soon as I see the ARP request, I look back at a livestream or connection to discord that will drop, so usually after. It does have an IPv6 address, have not tested whether this can still be reached at this point. Likewise for other LAN devices.

Comment: Also with the fresh install and updated drivers on the network adapters, I suspected this would “almost” clear the OS

Comment: Humans are not fast enough to visually see simultaneous events. This is counted in milliseconds.